# font-family style not working in wordpress menu

Tags: css, wordpress

I beg you,some one please look at this , i am helpless to get it out.
I am doing a site for my client and created a responsive menu.

The font style for the menu is not working even though I marked it as important.

My site url is.

http://sparrowhair.softcorp.ca/

The style i am trying to use is..   **Cocktail Shaker**

Please help me.. Client is very hurry..

I have only half an hour.. and trying it from morning.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry you're having trouble today but it's not our fault you've waited until the last minute.  Start by reading this please:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to fetch the font from Google Fonts, but it is no longer there. http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cocktail+Shaker is not a valid URL.

Try [downloading](http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/Cocktail+Shaker/) the font and store it on your server. That should do the trick :)

Comment: I have downloaded and kept in my theme folder. But its not working

Answer (score 0):

You declared the @font-face in css as 'sagar_menu' instead of 'Cocktail Shaker'. Edit your css to use that family like so:

```
.navbar {
    font-family: sagar_menu;
}
```

Comment: even if I mention cocktail shaker it is not affecting.. Are you getting the effect through inspect element..?

Comment: Thanks for Your replies.
My problem is solved now.
sagar_menu font will look almost similar to Cocktail shaker.So I used it for my requirement. Thanks
Phanindra

Comment: It does show up for me, I checked and I do not have the font installed on this machine. See http://nl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2zh3xc9&s=8 for the result. You should also change the css here: `.nav-menu li a {font-family: sagar_menu;}`